# android studio timer not canceling

Tags: java, android, timer, push-notification

i'm writing a task app where you can upload tasks with reminders through notification that will be send if you dont check the task as done. but even though i check the task it still pushes the notification.

i found other questions on stackoverflow like this one but none of the solutions helped me.

here is the code

`

```
@Override           
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                //if item is checked update status to 1 and stop timer
                myDB.updateStatus(item.getId(), 1);
                Reminder_stopTimer();
            }else{
                //if item is not checked update status to 0 and start timer
                myDB.updateStatus(item.getId(), 0);
                Reminder_startTimer();

            }

        }


    });

}

public void setTasks(List<ToDoModel> mList){
    this.mList = mList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    Reminder_startTimer();
}



//method to delete Task
public void deleteTask(int position){
    ToDoModel item = mList.get(position);
    //delete task from database
    myDB.deleteTask(item.getId());
    //delete task from list
    mList.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    Reminder_stopTimer();
}


public void startStop(){
    if (timerRunning){
        Reminder_stopTimer();
    }else {
        Reminder_startTimer();
    }
}
//timer for task reminder
public void Reminder_startTimer(){
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(TimeLeftInMilliseconds, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            activity.makeNotification();
        }
    }.start();

    timerRunning = true;
}

public void Reminder_stopTimer(){
    timerRunning = false;
    countDownTimer.cancel();

}
}
```

`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

suggest use `ticker`

```
val tickerChannel = ticker(delayMillis = 15 * 1000)
```